# Can county level info be brought into a map?

Tags: qgis

I have a csv file of Clovis projectile points that were recorded only with the county in which they were found, no coordinates at all, no shapefiles. Is there a way to bring these into a state map with counties to show county level finds?

---

I have a geocoded county outline set for VA. Imported with no problems. I have geocoded site locations for VA. Imported with no problems. Now I have 920 Clovis spear points that were recorded to the county level only and which are not geocoded in anyway, except that the county is listed. I asked the question here and was directed to MMGIS and got the same error message that 2 other folks got so that didn't work. Then tried to use the vector join. That brought in only some of the info from the Clovis csv file I wanted and then only up to the number of counties in VA (105). So how do I do this. The ArcGIS folks can do it but can QGIS do so and if so, can someone give this newbie step by step instructions as I have tried dozens of combinations to no effect that is useful. Thanks

Comment: Well if you have some kind of name (County-Name) or adress you could geocode this information and aggregate your information to the resulting locations

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by Clovis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clovis

---

**EDIT**

Here is a step-by-step Guide:

Download Virginia Tiger data at county level from: http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main

To avoid mistakes by misspelling, I use the FIPS code, as contained in the shapefile in field `COUNTYFP10`. Note that these are stored as string with three digits.

My sample csv data looks like this:

```
name;FIPS
test1;073
test2;017
test3;127
test4;043
test5;127
test6;081
test7;055
test8;179
test9;125
test10;021
test11;053
test12;143
test13;021
```

about 113 lines with random-generated FIPS code between 1 and 199.
Load the census data shapefile, and the csv as vector layer.

Rightclick on the csv layer, `Properties`, `Join` tab
click on the green plus, select `COUNTYFP10` in the second and `FIPS` in the third field.
You get your csv with county information added.

The last columns `INTPTLAT10` and `INTPTLON10` give the WGS84 coordinates of the county polygon centers. Save the layer as CSV, and add this layer as `Text delimited layer`.
X-Field should be `INTPTLON10`, Y-Field `INTPTLAT10`.

QGIS will ask you for CRS, select `WGS84, EPSG:4326`.

The result will be a point layer with only those counties where sample data was listed in the first CSV file. Labelling with field name looks like this (I added OSM background too):
[image: VA counties with sample points]

Comment: My best guess: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clovis_point

Comment: Clovis Points are a very common artifact in North American archaeology, bingo.